# Python Loop Only Returns One Result

Tags: python

Just started to learn Python and Beautiful Soup so please be gentle.  An issue that I have been struggling with is that while scraping I am only getting one return with the following code:

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.dailyfaceoff.com/teams/pittsburgh-penguins/line-combinations/'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"team-line-combination-wrap"})


for container in containers:
    name_container = container.findAll("span",{"class":"player-name"})
    name = name_container[0].text
    print(name)
```

Just not sure what is causing this to occur.  When I check name_container it contains all the results I was finding with the findAll, yet when the loop starts it only returns one result.  Any help/direction/guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: because u are only printing the 1st index of name_container

Comment: Welcome to SO, name_container[0] will return the first result from all the list items, you are printing the first element of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through all the `name_container` not just the `containers`:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.dailyfaceoff.com/teams/pittsburgh-penguins/line-combinations/'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")

data = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"team-line-combination-wrap"})


for container in data:
    name_container = container.findAll("span",{"class":"player-name"})
    for cont in name_container:
        print(cont.text)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Jake Guentzel
Sidney Crosby
Bryan Rust
.
.
.
Matt Murray
Olli Maatta

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: This definitely works.  Thanks so much for the input.  Being new to scraping it makes sense now.

Comment: @sanchja no worries, if the answer helped. You may mark it by clicking on the tick sign beside it to accept it. Cheers!